# Can surrogate class contain references to original class

Tags: c#, serialization, unity-game-engine, protocol-buffers, protobuf-net

I'm trying to create surrogate for third-party class called `Transform`. I need to serialize just a few of its public members, including some references to another such class instance and expose inner list of `Transforms`. So I wrote surrogate for it, but I'm not sure if one can define `[ProtoMember]` attribute on the surrogate's fields, which are of `Transform` type. Or should they be `TransformSurrogate`? Right now my code is:

```
[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault = true)]
public class TransformSurrogate {
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    Vector3 localPosition { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(2)]
    Vector3 localScale { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(3)]
    Quaternion localRotation { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(4, AsReference = true)]
    Transform parent { get; set; }
    [ProtoMember(5, AsReference = true)]
    List<Transform> children { get; set; }

    public static explicit operator TransformSurrogate(Transform transform) {
        if (transform == null) return null;
        var surrogate = new TransformSurrogate();
        surrogate.localPosition = transform.localPosition;
        surrogate.localRotation = transform.localRotation;
        surrogate.localScale = transform.localScale;
        surrogate.parent = transform.parent;
        surrogate.children = new List<Transform>();
        for (int i = 0; i < transform.childCount; ++i) {
            surrogate.children.Add(transform.GetChild(i));
        }
        return surrogate;
    }

    public static explicit operator Transform(TransformSurrogate surrogate) {
        if (surrogate == null) return null;
        var transform = new GameObject().transform;
        transform.localPosition = surrogate.localPosition;
        transform.localRotation = surrogate.localRotation;
        transform.localScale = surrogate.localScale;
        transform.parent = (Transform) surrogate.parent;
        foreach (var child in surrogate.children) {
            child.parent = transform;
        }
        return transform;
    }
}
```

Dont pay much attention to `Vector3` and `Quaternion` classes - they are easily serialized structures. So I define my own `RuntimeTypeModel` for `Transform` type like this:

```
Model.Add(typeof(Transform), false).SetSurrogate(typeof(TransformSurrogate));
```

However, I've got an error during deserialization, telling me that Protobuf is unable to convert between classes. I'm thinking that it is because of mixing original class within surrogate class, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This is very hard to answer in the context of a complicated type that depends on non-core types; do you have an example that demonstrates the problem just using simple local types?

Comment: @MarcGravell right now I'm trying to model this situation in easier environment, however if you wonder what are Vector3 and Quaternion types - you can skip those, since they are simple structures and I successfully serialized them. My main focus right now is on Transform class only. Transform is Unity3D built-in type, if it helps.

Answer (score 1):

For some data types yes it will work, I'm doing this exact same thing right now (writing a surrogate for a Unity3D transform). Earlier, I tested on a MeshSurrogate. Here is how the code starts...

```
[ProtoContract(AsReferenceDefault = true)]
    [ProtoSurrogate(typeof(Mesh))]
    sealed class MeshSurrogate {
        [ProtoMember(1)]
        Matrix4x4[] bindposes;

        [ProtoMember(2)]
        BoneWeight[] boneWeights;

/* Lots more follows */
```

(the ProtoSurrogateAttribute is custom... it does what you might expect)
It works just fine serializing and deserializing fields of the original non-surrogate types for all the data types.

Transform gets more interesting though. Here's a potential problem - AsReference reportedly does not play well with surrogates - https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/issues/detail?id=352 Too bad, because this is core to our Unity serialization strategy.

I'll update if I get this working.

**Update:**
This turns out to be pretty involved.

The solution I've got rolling is that basically anything that inherits UnityEngine.Object gets a surrogate that contains 3 and only 3 members - an instanceIdBeforeSerialization (obtained with UnityEngine.Object.GetInstanceID()), a "shell" and a "data". The shell and data are only populated if this surrogate is the first to be encountered during this serialization, otherwise they are null. Shells are responsible for instantiating objects, and data for populating them each in a [OnDeserialized] method. When the shell creates an object it stores it in a table with a mapping from it's old instance id to it's new instance id, so that when any surrogate gets cast to the original type it only needs to search for it's new object in the table. Because shells get placed earlier on the stream, all objects are at least initialized before something needs to reference them in the object graph.

Unfortunately I was not able to get the Data classes to store references to the Unity objects directly, but this is a library so the maximum convenience goes to the user and not the author.

Now that the kinks are worked out it looks like this approach is going to work well. I'll see if my employer will allow it to go to the asset store.

**Update:**
This will be going in the asset store when it's finished. There's a lot of surrogates to add first so it may be a while.